# unique key based on 2 columns in SQl Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

is it posible to have SQL Server to have a unique key based on 2 columns?

I can have duplicates in both columns but not at the same time:

```
MfgID  :   CustNum   
1      :     Cust01   
1      :     Cust02  
2      :     Cust02  
1      :     Cust03  
3      :     Cust03  
3      :     Cust04  
1      :     Cust02
```

In the example above all of these would be fine EXCEPT the last row.  I'd like SQL Server to kck out an error on this for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TableName_MfgID_CustNum ON TableName
(
        MfgID  ,
        Column2
) WITH( IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
```

Comment: This is by far most simple and elegant solution.

Comment: Shoud it not be a KEY in stead of an index?

Answer (score 9):

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  MfgID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CustNum VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT unique_1 UNIQUE (MfgID, CustNum)
)
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT unique_1 UNIQUE(fgID, CustNum)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It is called **composite primary key**.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  MfgID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CustNum VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (MfgID, CustNum)
)
```

Comment: Doesn't have to be primary key it cat be unique composite index too.