# How do I apply unique constraint on two columns SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns type and name in the database. I want to apply a unique constraint where the name is unique within each type.

```
Type   Name
 A     ABC
 R     ABC
 B     ABC
```

should be allowed whereas

```
Type  Name
 A    ABC
 A    ABC
```

should not be allowed

How to enforce this constraint where name is unique within each type?

Thanks,

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184194/unique-key-based-on-2-columns-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a multi column unique constraint like this

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD UNIQUE (Type, Name)
```

That will enforce the rules you describe.

Answer (score 0):

While creating table you can do

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable(
  Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  Type   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Type, Name)
)
```

Or you can alter your table with

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (Type, Name)
```

After that I executed following four.. (last one failed)

```
insert into YourTable values('AB','ABD')
insert into YourTable values('AA','ABD')
insert into YourTable values('AA','ABC')
insert into YourTable values('AA','ABD')
```

Thanks,
Jigar

Comment: This does not work I want the name to be unique within each type. The name can be repeated in different types. The above method does not allow duplicate enteries for different type.

Comment: I would **really** not suggest having two VARCHAR(255) as the primary key of any table...